# locating resources in spring mvc app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I want to programmatically locate the relative path of files from a method in a `controller` class in a `spring mvc` web application so that I can read the contents of those files into `java`.  I use `eclipse`, but this will be bundled into a war file.

The app needs to retrieve files from elsewhere, place those files in a folder, and then in this case read the files from a given folder into java.  So the files should not be bundled in the war, but the code in the war needs to be able to read and write files from the hard drive using urls that are relative to the application root.

**My two questions are: 1.) So where should I place the files within my eclipse project?  2.) How can I change the code below so that the files are found?**

In my first attempt, relative to the root of the eclipse project, I placed the files in `src/main/resources/xml` and used the following code, but I am getting error messages indicating that the app cannot find the files because it is looking relative to the eclipse installation and not relative to the eclipse project:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someMethodName(Map<String, Object> model) {
    String inputpath = "src\\main\\resources\\xml\\";
    File folder = new File(inputpath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            StreamSource inputStream = new StreamSource(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            //do some stuff with the inputstream
        }
    }
    return "redirect:/someotherurl";
}
```

Comment: After reading your comment I have decided to delete the answer.

Comment: @myqyl4 OK.  That is your choice.  But why?

Comment: It is the wrong answer for your question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'elsewhere'? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve in your code; you seem to have accepted that "the files should not be bundled in the war", but then you store them under `webapp/` anyway and seem surprised that it doesn't work? You should read up on what classpath is, especially in a servlet webapp context.

Comment: @kryger Thank you for looking at this.  In production, the files are going to come from a different server.  But in testing, I am just going to put them somewhere on the development machine and write code to import them into the application.  **This question, right now, is about where to put them when they are imported into the app, and then how to find them programmatically.**  I do very much appreciate resources for reading.  I read all day long every day.  But I am working on a deadline and I would really appreciate it if you would be kind enough to help me with a more specific answer.

Comment: Choose a dedicated folder on the deployed server and put them there. This can be any directory your app has write access to, ex. `/home/some-user/app-name/dir`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you.  There will be times when this app will be in shared hosting, so the code will not have access to absolute paths.  Right now I am in an eclipse project.

Comment: @kryger I get the same empty results when I change to a relative address inside the classpath, such as: `inputpath = "src\\main\\resources\\xml\\";`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am able to import the files into java from an absolute url, but then when I pass the `inputstream` in the code above to another method, the `inputstream` throws an error that the `absolute path of the eclipse installation` does not contain the resource that was found from a different `absolute path`.  I am hoping that using `relative paths` can avoid that kind of confusion.